# How to stop a wget mirror?

Tags: wget, gnu

I accidentally mirrored a whole website using wget. Whenever I try to delete the downloaded file, it keeps reappearing & trying to download again. How do I stop this?

I tried looking through the wget GNU documentation, but I did not find anything about ceasing a command.

Comment: How are you running the command, in cron or what? Please show your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.